# Using regex replace to transform an expression

Tags: c#, regex

is it possible to transform an expression like

```
{op1 == op2, #} && {op3 > op4, 1, 2} && op5 == op6
```

to

```
op1 ==_# op2 && op3 >_1_2 op4 && op5 == op6
```

So, all occurences after the comma should be placed seperated by an underline after the operator (==, >,<,<=, etc...). opX can be any alphanumerical value.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: This is not easily done with regex. Not in one pass at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After Qtax's comment, I just wrote a solution:

```
var st = "{op1 == op2, #} && {op3 > op4, 1, 2} && op5 == op6";

var regex = "{.*?}";
for (var match = Regex.Match(st, regex); match.Success; match = Regex.Match(st, regex))
{
    var oldString = match.Value; // {op1 == op2, #} 

    var op = oldString.Split(' ').ToList()[1].Trim(); // == 
    var csv = oldString.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim()).ToList(); // [0] = "{op1 == op2" [1] = "#}"

    var expression = csv[0].Remove(0,1); // op1 == op2
    csv.RemoveAt(0);

    var extension = "_" + String.Join("_", csv);
    extension = extension.Remove(extension.Length-1); // _#

    var newString = expression.Replace(op, op + extension);

    st = st.Replace(oldString, newString); 
}
```